# How do I build random objects with multiple variables?

Tags: java

This is my main program. What I am trying to achieve here is for each "HeadPhones" set to have a randomly generated color and manufacturer. Currently when the program is run, the variables all come out the same aside from what I have preset.

```java
package testheadphones;

import java.util.Random;

public class TestHeadPhones {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] manufacturers = {"Skullcandy", "Klipsch", "Grado", "Shure",
    "Bose", "Beats", "Sony"};
    String[] colors = {"blue", "black", "green", "red", "purple", "pink",
    "white", "orange", "yellow"};



    Random random = new Random();
    int randColor = random.nextInt(2);
    String color = colors[randColor];
    int randMan = random.nextInt(2);
    String manufacturer = manufacturers[randMan];


    //Build three headphone sets.
    //Each set is encased in "{}" just for organization
    HeadPhones set1 = new HeadPhones();{
    set1.setIsPluggedIn(true);
    set1.getManufacturer();
    set1.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
    set1.getVolume();
    set1.setVolume(2);
    set1.getColor();
    set1.setColor(color);
    }

    HeadPhones set2 = new HeadPhones();{
    set2.setIsPluggedIn(true);
    set2.getManufacturer();
    set2.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
    set2.getVolume();
    set2.setVolume(1);
    set2.getColor();
    set2.setColor(color);
    }

    HeadPhones set3 = new HeadPhones();{
    set3.setIsPluggedIn(true);
    set3.getManufacturer();
    set3.setManufacturer(manufacturer);
    set3.getVolume();
    set3.setVolume(3);
    set3.getColor();
    set3.setColor(color);
    }

    System.out.println(set1.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(set2.toString());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(set3.toString());

}

}
```

Here is my class file.

```
    package testheadphones;

import java.util.Random;

public class HeadPhones {

//Constant Declarations
public static final int LOW = 1;
public static final int MEDIUM = 2;
public static final int HIGH = 3;

//Private Declarations
private int volume = MEDIUM;
private boolean pluggedIn = false;
private String manufacturer = null;
private String color = null;

Random random = new Random();

//Default Constructor
public void HeadPhones (int volume, String manufacturer, String Color){
    pluggedIn = false;
    manufacturer = "Sony";
    color = "red";
    volume = MEDIUM;
}

//Getter and Setter
public int getVolume(){
    return volume;
}
public void setVolume(int volume){
    this.volume = volume;
}
public String getManufacturer(){
    return manufacturer;
}
public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer){
    this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
}
public boolean getIsPluggedIn(){
    return pluggedIn;
}
public void setIsPluggedIn(boolean pluggedIn){
    this.pluggedIn = pluggedIn;
}
public String getColor(){
    return color;
}
public void setColor(String color){
    this.color = color;
}

public String toString(){
    String plugIn = this.pluggedIn == true ? "plugged in. " : "not plugged"
            + " in. ";

    String earBuds = "Your headphones are " + plugIn + "They are: " + 
            this.color + " " + this.manufacturer + " and are turned up to "
   + this.volume;

    return earBuds;
}

}
```

Comment: Random object could be unboxed from random values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is unclear I'll try to understand what you want.

I suppose you want to find a random element in the whole array and not only the 2 first elements: `random.nextInt(colors.length);` and `random.nextInt(manufacturers.length);` instead of `random.nextInt(colors.length);`.

You create an integer and you use it for the 3 headphones. You probably want to pick a new color and a new manufacturer for each headphone. Then replace `setX.setManufacturer(manufacturer);` and `setX.setColor(color);` with:

```java
setX.setManufacturer(manufacturers[random.nextInt(manufacturers.length)]);
setX.setColor(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to implement this on each setter and generate a random variable. I struggled with it for a while. I knew what I wanted to do just couldn't figure out exactly how to do it.

Comment: Just a side note. This also allowed me to omit a few lines of code which cleaned it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Possible One error that i can see you are `generating random number between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value i.e 2(exclusive)` i.e only two values are `generated 1 and 0`. you need to generate it between more ranges

Workaround this

```
Random random = new Random();
    int randColor = random.nextInt(manufacturers.length);
    String color = colors[randColor];
    int randMan = random.nextInt(colors.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
    int randMan = random.nextInt(2)
```

You are saying the Random class to generate a random int between 0 and 1 (2 exclusive).
Probably what you would like to do is generate a random number between 0 and

```
    manufacturers.length
```

Same applies to colors. So what you need is:

```
    int randColor = random.nextInt(colors.length);
    int randMan = random.nextInt(manufacturers.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you want:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] manufacturers = {"Skullcandy", "Klipsch", "Grado", "Shure", "Bose", "Beats", "Sony"};  
    String[] colors = {"blue", "black", "green", "red", "purple", "pink", "white", "orange", "yellow"};

    ArrayList<HeadPhones> list = new ArrayList<HeadPhones>();

    Random random = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int volume = i + 1;

        int randManufacturers = random.nextInt(manufacturers.length);
        String manufacturer = manufacturers[randManufacturers];

        int randColor = random.nextInt(colors.length);
        String color = colors[randColor];

        HeadPhones headPhones = new HeadPhones(volume, manufacturer, color);

        list.add(headPhones);
    }

    //Print it
   foreach(HeadPhones headPhones: list){
       System.out.println(headPhones.toString());
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You created only one random set of variables values for all yours Headphone object. Maybe you should try to create methods which would give you proper random variables, like:

```
public static String randomColor(){
    Random random = new Random();
    String[] colors = {"blue", "black", "green", "red", "purple", "pink",
            "white", "orange", "yellow"};
    int randColor = random.nextInt(colors.length);
    return colors[randColor];
}
```

Then you can call for example:

```
headphone.setColor(randomColor());
```

and easily reuse it where you want.